# Thunderbird won't start

Tags: thunderbird, glib

Restarted my computer, and noticed that Thunderbird which is set to auto-start did not start. So I clicked on the icon on the taskbar, the box highlighted the icon, the cursor spun around for a minute and then just quit. I tried clicking the icon on my Cairo dock, and going into the start programs folder and clicking there, same thing. I tried to start it with a terminal command and got this error:

```
(process:3354): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

I tried reinstalling with Synaptic, still no luck. I don't want to uninstall and lose all my settings unless I just have to. So does anyone have any other ideas, before I uninstall?

EDIT New Info; ardvark, I did post on both boards because I don't know if its a TB problem,  or a Ubuntu problem. Now the response I got over there lead me to open system monitor and I found that TB was still running in the processes, so I ended the process, still would not start, Then had to do a gksudo nautilus, and delete a lock, and parentlock file inside the TB folder. Tried to start the TB -profilemanager, error said file did not exist. Uninstalled and reinstalled tried to start nothing, tried to start  with terminal and got the error

```
(process:3637): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Then I noticed that I am still getting my new email msg popups. So it's running somewhere.

vfbsilva First that was the whole error msg (on both of them). I tried to start with the command "sudo thunderbird" error was

```
(process:4261): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed

(thunderbird:4261): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/robby/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
07:32:15 INFO firetray.Handler OS=Linux, ABI=x86_64-gcc3, XULrunner=17.0.8
07:32:15 INFO firetray.Handler inMailApp=true, inBrowserApp=false, appHasChat=true
07:32:15 INFO firetray.Handler isChatProvided=true
```

The link you gave me was for FF, and I was unsure how to change the chown command to point to TB. 
Everyone thanks for the responses.

Comment: Take a look here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2142601&page=2 
Was that the whole output message?

Comment: I also noted a response to your question here... http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2738171 Regards...

Comment: Try starting thunderbird from a terminal `CTRL+ALT+T`, post the message you get in the terminal.

Comment: After a couple of unrelated restarts TB started working again. Don't know why. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if I had the same exact bug as you, but I had something very similar. Thunderbird crashed (this is my 2nd day using it and I'm already 110% frustrated with it) and then wouldn't reopen.

```
/home/mhaase $ thunderbird

(process:11979): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

On a hunch, I wondered if there was still somebackground process...

```
/home/mhaase $ ps aux | grep thunder
mhaase    2655  5.2  2.0 1720260 341164 ?      Sl   Jan26  45:39     /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
mhaase   12036  0.0  0.0  12164  2080 pts/8    S+   09:19   0:00 grep --color=auto thunder
```

After killing that process, Thunderbird starts normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem this afternoon, though this morning was OK. Thunderbird would not start from the normal icon, and from a terminal it gave me:

```
"GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed".
```

What I did was open `htop` from the command line, search for `thunderbird` (there were numerous instances showing up there) and kill one of them. That kills all of them. Then Thunderbird started normally.